# Allowing access-control-origin in Django on the development server?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I'm trying to use `rest_framework_swagger` with Django 1.9. I'm currently running on the built-in Django development server, and whenever I try to access the `docs/` subdomain where the Swagger documentation should be, I get an error message saying: `Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.` How do I fix this for the Django development server?

Comment: CORS limitations never apply to direct HTTP requests, only to requests made by remote ressources indirectly. So what part of loading the page is not working? And BTW `docs/` is not a proper subdomain.

Comment: CORS only intercepts cross-domain requests. If it is such a case and you are accessing url of an application running on django, checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38188591/6522072), if this could help you.